# Using Styled-Components `.attrs` with TypeScript (Props don't merge)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-tsx

When I do this:

```
const Button = styled.button.attrs((props:ButtonProps) => ({
    primary: props.buttonType === 'primary',
    secondary: props.buttonType === 'secondary',
    critical: props.buttonType === 'critical',
    small: props.buttonSize === 'small',
}))
```

I get the following error with TS:
[image]

My Types are as follows

```
type ButtonProps = {
    buttonType?: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'critical';
    children?: React.ReactChild | React.ReactChild[];
    buttonSize?: 'small' | 'medium';
};
```

The problem fixes itself however when I pass down the original props with the edited attributes like thus:

```
const Button = styled.button.attrs((props:ButtonProps) => ({
    primary: props.buttonType === 'primary',
    secondary: props.buttonType === 'secondary',
    critical: props.buttonType === 'critical',
    small: props.buttonSize === 'small',
  ...props
}))
```

I've seen elsewhere online I'm supposed to type props in `attrs` the same way I'd do so with plain styled-components like here:

```
const Button = styled.button.attrs<ButtonProps>((props) => ({
    primary: props.buttonType === 'primary',
    secondary: props.buttonType === 'secondary',
    critical: props.buttonType === 'critical',
    small: props.buttonSize === 'small',
}))
```

But this just gives me the same error as in the image :/

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but i solved it by removing attrs. This is my code. I hope it will help you

[styled define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AQjQ.png)

[component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUIM4.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32511779)